# Is NLB a good way to keep a website available while deploying new code?

Tags: asp.net, iis, nlb

I want to be able to deploy a new version of my asp.net/mvc website without loosing client session state or causing any downtime.  The way I'm thinking of accomplishing this is by creating a Windows Network Load Balancing server so that clients can reach it via a single url such as https://mysite.org/.  It would then redirect traffic to one of two other sites (A.mysite.org or B.mysite.org).  I'll set the NLB's affinity to Single, and disable site B so that all sessions are are directed to site A.  When I need to deploy a new version of the website, I'll deploy to site B, enable site B, and disable site A.  So, everybody that was on site A can stay there (using version 1) until they log off. All new sessions will connect to site B and run version 2.  The next time I deploy, I'll do the reverse.

I've never used NLB.  Is this appropriate?  Is there a simpler, easier way?

How does NLB know when a request from client X already has a session on A or B?  Ie.  when they log off the website, and try to login again, will the nlb send them to the same site they were on before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few considerations here

Firstly, rather than juggling the affinity on your NLB, you will probably be better storing your ASP.NET Sessions in [StateServer or SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) based Session management to allow web clients (or web service clients) to access your site without 'sticky' affinity. Once you've set up the StateServer or created the SQL Session DB, it should be a simple change to your app's web config.

NLB itself works great for keeping your site up while you upgrade your site. You will typically drainstop a server in the cluster before reinstalling your app to it, test it, and then bring it back into the NLB cluster, before repeating the process with the next server etc.

AFAIK, [NLB Single Affinity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687542.aspx) works at TCP/IP level and is does not interrogate ASP.NET sessions. Basically any connection from the same client IP to the same server IP:Port combination will be directed to the same server. Also AFAIK, both servers will be sharing the NLB IP (In addition to any existing IP's they have).
Since it seems your site uses SSL, it seems that unless you have affinity, that the SSL session keys will need to be [renegotiated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/ff711653) on each request, which could have performance implications.